# given a word forming a meaningful word by adding spaces in between them

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, trie, suffix-array

You are given a string example "Iamastudent" without any spaces. You will be provided with a predefined dictionary function which verifies whether a given word is present in the dictionary or not. Using this function you have to insert the spaces in the string a print it as "I am a student".

its my interview question and told me too solve in c++, i solved it using dynamic programming but he was not satisfied 
the solution i gave is
 same as in the below question

[Given a phrase without spaces add spaces to make proper sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543435/given-a-phrase-without-spaces-add-spaces-to-make-proper-sentence)

he asked me to do it using **trie** or **suffix array** but i couldnt able to figure the solution can any one help me

Comment: I think you previous post complexity can be improved by
finding largest common sub-sequence starting with str[pos] from dictionary.
Again starting from pos+=(length of sub-sequence found above) and repeating the search.

Comment: can u be more clear please?

Answer (score 0):

[Find words and put spaces after them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534158/find-words-and-put-spaces-after-them/46581990#46581990)

The answer is to use Trie data structure. Create Trie with possible words and keep traversing. with Trie you can generate many different possible words.

now here "iamastudent" with Trie you could generate these words.

```
i, a, am, a, as, student
```

now you have to make a proper sentence out of these words. Here the possible solution is markov chain. A markov chain is data structure where it holds probability for next word after a word. so markov chain will be.

```
"i" : [ "am", "did", "went" ...],
"a" : [ "tree", "dog" ..]
"am" : [ "a" ...]
```

Now you these many data in sequence

```
[i], [a, am], [a, as], [student]
```

> Note: I grouped all elements which starts with same character in one
>   list.

start with **"i"**
next word is "a". but in markov chain "a" is not there. so go for next word. like this you can continue.

from here onwards it is a dfs search for a valid sentence. well, it was a nice and tricky question.

Answer (score -1):

If there is a unique solution of splitting the sentence then doing it with a trie is simple:

1. if there are characters in the input string start walking down from the root consuming characters from the string. otherwise terminate.
2. if it is a compressed trie you will find a mark whenever a prefix is a complete word otherwise if you reach a leaf that's when you output a space
3. go back to 1 (walking down from the root) starting from the current position in the string

You are done when there are no more characters in the string (you may want to check that at this point you are not traversing the tree).

If the solution is not unique, then whenever you reach the end of the string and you are not at a mark or a leaf in the tree you need to backtrack to the previous space you emitted. You need a stack for positions in the input string.