# Find words and put spaces after them

Tags: string, algorithm, pointers, dictionary, search

Once I was asked a question in an interview and I am still not clear how to solve it. Or couldn't even get close to it.

**Q. Given is a  of series of characters eg."thisisachallengingquestion", Write a program to put space after every word except the last one**

***Input :*** "thisisachallengingquestion"

***Output:*** "this is a challenging question"

---

**My Approach**

1. Assume given a dictionary object containing all the words that can be in a string.
2. Traverse through all the letters with 2 pointers. Using the [runner technique](https://leetcode.com/articles/two-pointer-technique/), keep on tracking the for actual word to match the key in object.

example:

**Initially**: Pointer 1 and Pointer 2 both are at index 0. Compares "t" in dictionary object key.(NO)

**1st Iteration**: "th" <- if this contains as key in dictionary object (NO)

**2nd Iteration**: "thi" (NO)

**3rd Iteration**: "this" (YES)

Push the word from *0th index to 3rd index* in new Array and put space (" ") after it.

Place the *1st* and *2nd* pointer to the value of *(2nd pointer + 1)* and  and so on till the length of the given string.

---

Please let me know if there is any better solution to this.

**Questions can arise like:**

1.Dictionary is not provided?

2.How can we do without using another Array?(Javascript allows dynamic array, so how can we use `splice` or can we use `splice`?)

Comment: Hey looking into it, by the way without dictionary you need something like NLP processing

Comment: I will be checking NLP prosessing. How about the dictionary approach?
Because, this question was for entry level position and NLP seems like a very high level approach, right?

Comment: [Word Break Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/solution/)- This is somewhat like what we are looking for, I found it on leetcode.

Comment: if a word is a prefix of another word, for example, "cat" is a prefix of "catastrophe", how would your solution behave?

Comment: That's also another problem. Still figuring out how to do it. I will keep updating.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh yes dictionary approach is the way to go for this kind of problem.....

Comment: Perfect, I will try to code accordingly and will post the working code.

Comment: As halfo pointed out, you need to try all valid splits for the first word, then repeat the logic, so a DP approach as mcdowella suggested is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pseudo code.

```
words = Trie()
for word in dictionary:
    words. insert(word)

let str be the string.

let output be array
for char in string:
    words.walk(char)
    output.append(char)
    If words.isAtEndofWord() then
         output.append(' ')
         words.seek(0)

output = toString(output)
```

Trie is data structure to create dictionary. You can add functionality to walk with tree nodes unless it reaches end of a word.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with dynamic programming. Work through the array from left to right. Update an array of bits as you go to show whether there is a solution that ends at a given point. At each position consider all of the dictionary words that match a suffix of the text ending at that point. Look at the bit array and see if the text that would come just before a proposed word ends neatly. If so, set the bit for that position. When you get to the end, if it turns out there is a solution (final bit in bit-array set) work backwards from right to left, checking with the bit array to make sure that any word you chose leaves you in a position to find a solution for the portion of the text to the left of it.

(This solves the problem of finding possible matches with different lengths - if there is a chain of words that accounts neatly for all the text, this will find it)

Comment: This should be right, but I am having trouble understanding it. I will research more about your solution today.